# Structuring Data Received from Kafka Topic

Tags: apache-kafka, avro

I have fetched some data from a kafka topic. I have used this configuration in the yml file

key-deserializer: **org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer**

value-deserializer: **org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer**

The data I got in console is

?8Enterprise recommended by AC

Is this an Avro Data??
And if is it so.. What should I do to convert it as Json data. Do I need to convert or deserialize??

Answer (score 0):

depends on the way you have gererate the message before write it to a topic.
If you have deserialized with String Deserializar and your output seems correct, probably you also used the String Serializer to write the value of the message in the topic.

This is not Avro or structured data. You can use json or Avro to serialize data when creating the message and then use the same deserializer when consuming the messages to get the message back with the srtuctured data.

If you tell me your programming language maybe i can give you an example.

I hope It helps